# How do I make surfaces more smoother/organic?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I've been tinkering with my model for the better part of the week, and am kinda in a rut. I'm trying to make a turtleneck for my character, but it looks really inorganic and a little bit blocky. I'll supply with a screenshot for context. Some background, I used a combination of shrinkwrap, mirror and solidify modifier to attain this where I am right now. I highlighted in red outlines in what I mean, as you can see the weird crease from the mirror modifier in the middle that I'm trying to get rid of, and the other parts of the turtleneck that look very blocky. How do I make it look more organic and turtleneck-y? Any help would be appreciated, as I spent a good chunk of time trying to fix this.

[image]

Let me know if you need any more info or need clarification.

Comment: Mirror modifier issue - you have inperfection in vertex position. Select them and set 0 on X axis or increase Merge Limit in modifier. Make it more organic - model it more organic Im not sure if here someone can come with some advice ...

Comment: Thanks for the help! The mirror modifier fix works like a charm by increasing the merge limit. Still trying to figure out the blocky issue with the belt/bracers. sculpting won't really work with the solidify modifier, so I'm trying to extrude and sculpt. Will update.

Comment: Update: It seems the best way to tackle this would be through making a couple extra rectangles before shading smooth. It looks a bit clunky still, but looks better than before.